# How to make ~/.vimrc run last

Tags: vim

Using :scriptnames I see that my local .vimrc runs in 9Th position out of 24 total scripts.  Somewhere in a script(s) in position(s) 10-24 my configuration commands are getting reset to something else. Currently I have set F2 to do :so ~/.vimrc which works but I would like to not have to do that.  So is there a way to make my .vimrc run in the 24th position or in last position?

Answer (score 2):

Start vim with:

```
vim -S ~/.vimrc myfile.txt
```

You can define an alias in `~/.bashrc`, so you don't need to type it every time:

```
alias vim='vim -S ~/.vimrc'
```

This causes `~/.vimrc` to be sourced again after all other scripts have been sourced and the file to edit has been read. It is the same thing as doing `:so ~/.vimrc` when vim is running.

Comment: Doh. I knew that.  But I'm guessing that some script makes "calls" to all of these other scripts (maybe even my .vimrc).  I might try to look for that sometime.  Thanks for your reply. Sorry my status is too lame to give you a checkmark.

Comment: You're welcome. I already upvoted your question to give you some reputation. Go collect some more, then come back to accept the answer ;)